# Arranging a list by row with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

am trying to organize a list of images by row, having that there should be a max of 4 in each row, i seem to get the first four but it doesn't get the next set but rather repeats the first four.

```
var imageLinksSource = $(".images-links .imgOriginals"),
listContainer = $(".imgsList"),
dispType = $(".dispType").val(),
arrCounter = 0;


while (arrCounter < imageLinksSource.size()) {
    arrCounter++;
    var $slices = imageLinksSource.slice(0, 4);
    $("<div class='row-fluid'/>").append($slices.clone()).appendTo(".imgsList");
    $slices.remove();
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see. For starters your while condition is weird. You are comparing number of rows with the current array size of your `imageLinksSource` array. Use something like `imageLinksSource.size() > 0`.

Also, slice does not modify the original array, so that's why you are always getting the same elements.

Example:

```
while ( imageLinksSource.size() > 0 )
{
    var slices = imageLinksSource.splice(0, 4);
    $("<div class='row-fluid'/>").append($(slices)).appendTo(".imgsList");
}
```

Note that I used *splice* instead of *slice*. Haven't tested the whole code though.

Comment: @user2553780that created an infinite while loop!

Comment: @DanielBarde That's because the array size is always the same, you are not modifying it.

Comment: please can you explain clearly and help with a better suggestion on how to get this done? thanks.

Comment: @DanielBarde Updated my answer in order to give you a more explicit suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Slice does not modify the array so you need to either modify the code to include some offset (ie. `imageLinksSource.slice(4*arrCounter, 4*arrCounter + 4);`) or remove the first four elements from the list.

For example:

```
while (arrCounter < imageLinksSource.size()) {
    var $slices = imageLinksSource.slice(arrCounter, arrCounter + 4);
    $("<div class='row-fluid'/>").append($slices.clone()).appendTo(".imgsList");
    arrCounter += 4;
};
```

Comment: that only displayed the last four rows.